# Getting "root" folder of orgmode package installation in emacs via elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

How can I get the folder in which org-mode is installed in emacs? Depending on the way it was installed, it will be different. Is there a variable which holds this value?

I would need it to access a file which is part of the org-mode installation.

I am not looking for a particular library, but an .R file, which is an R file which I want to load programmatically into R (from elisp code).

So using

`(locate-library "ob-R")
"/Users/rainerkrug/.emacs.d/org-mode/lisp/ob-R.elc"`

I would then have to use the following:

`(concat (locate-library "ob-R") "/../etc/")
"/Users/rainerkrug/.emacs.d/org-mode/lisp/ob-R.elc/../etc/"`

And I still have to get rid of the ob-R.elc

This works, but I am looking for a function which gives me the path

`(IS-THERE-SOMETHING-LIKE-THIS "org")
"/Users/rainerkrug/.emacs.d/org-mode/"`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs provides a rich set of file name manipulation functions which easily solve your problem:

```
(expand-file-name "../etc/R" (file-name-directory (locate-library "ob-R")))
```

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`M-x locate-library RET org RET`

or, if you would like to open:

`M-x find-library RET org RET`

Comment: I am not looking for a particular library, but an .R file, which is an R file which I want to load programmatically into R (from elisp code). So using (locate-library "ob-R") would work, but then I have to use "../" to get to the root directory - no train smash, but not elegant.

Comment: Why not just `M-x locate-library RET org RET`? It is the same library location for `org.el` and for `ob-R.el`.

Comment: Well - this doesn't make a difference. Please see my edits to clarify the question.

Comment: Ok, I see. I don't see other ways. Suggested one is quite good for me and I don't see any problem if it is required to get parent directory...

Comment: For example: `(file-name-directory (directory-file-name (file-name-directory (locate-library "org"))))`

Comment: Works - thanks. I have found a different solution, but will accept yours as answer if you add this to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Seems @juanleon provided the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
(org-find-library-dir "org")
```

Or, in your case:

```
(concat (org-find-library-dir "org") "etc/R")
```

Comment: Where does `org-find-library-dir` come from?

Comment: org-compat.el --- Compatibility code for Org-mode (I have it in /usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/org; and I have emacs from debian package 24.3+1-2~ppa2~precise1).  I assumed it is part of org-mode because of the path, but maybe I am mislead.

Comment: I'm using Emacs 24.4, and I don't have this function.  Looks like it was removed in Org 8.x. Emacs 24.3 still has 7.9 or so...

Comment: Odd, I have emacs-verison `24.3.50.1` and org-mode `8.2.3a` and the `org-find-library-dir` is defined in `org-compat.el`. It also appears to still exist in the [source for trunk](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/org/org-compat.el?h=trunk#n385).

Comment: Indeed.  I just didn't have it loaded.  Sorry for the hassle, my bad.

Comment: Thanks for org-find-library-dir - nice finction. But this one only adds `etc/R` to the org library path, which results in my case in `/Users/rainerkrug/.emacs.d/org-mode/lisp/etc/R`, dut I would need `/Users/rainerkrug/.emacs.d/org-mode/etc/R`. I could add `../etc/R` but would like to avoid using the `../`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please see the accepted answer - the org-find-library-dir is an undocumented macro so I prefer to use standard emacs functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do this programmatically, you could use `M-x describe-mode` and in the description one of first lines is `Org mode defined in org.el` The link to org.el is clickable, and leads to org-mode's directory.

Comment: Thanks - but I have to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which is efectively using locate-library and to truncate the not-needed elements (file name and last dir) and assembles them again as a path:

```
(locate-library "org")
"/Users/rainerkrug/.emacs.d/org-mode/lisp/org.elc"

(split-string (locate-library "org") "/")
("" "Users" "rainerkrug" ".emacs.d" "org-mode" "lisp" "org.elc")


(butlast (split-string (locate-library "org") "/") 2)
("" "Users" "rainerkrug" ".emacs.d" "org-mode")

(append (butlast (split-string (locate-library "org") "/") 2) '("etc" "R"))
("" "Users" "rainerkrug" ".emacs.d" "org-mode" "etc" "R")

(mapconcat 'identity
           (append (butlast (split-string (locate-library "org") "/") 2) '("etc" "R"))
           "/")
"/Users/rainerkrug/.emacs.d/org-mode/etc/R"
```

As pointed out in the comments, the usage of split-string is suboptimal. Please see accepted answer for the best approach.

Comment: Please use `file-name-directory` and `file-name-nondirectory` instead of splitting by `/`.

Comment: I am doing two things after splitting: 1) removing the file name - you are right I could do this with `file-name-directory` but also go one directory back (`..`). Could you please give me an information on how I could achieve this, apart from addind `..`? I would prefer a function, as I don't know if my approach also works under Windows.